# How do I add a 5 digit ZIP code validation to a Contact7 form?

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-contact-form-7, validation

I have an address form generated via Contact7. I need to validate there is a 5 digit zip code.

According to the [docs](https://contactform7.com/2015/03/28/custom-validation/), I came up with this function and placed it in my functions.php file

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_text*', 'custom_zip_validation_filter', 20, 2 );


function custom_zip_validation_filter( $result, $tag ) {
  if ( 'zip' == $tag->name ) {
    $zip = isset( $_POST['zip'] ) ? trim( $_POST['zip'] ) : '';
    $result = '/^([0-9]{5})?$/i';
  
    if (!preg_match($result, $zip, $matches)) {
            $result->invalidate($tag, "Please enter a valid zip code" );
        }
  }
  
  return $result;
}
```

Then in my Contact7 form, I put this line for the zip code `[text* zip class:zip id:zip placeholder "ZIP"]`

However, when I go to the form and input the ZIP code, I am able to submit a ZIP code of less than 5 digits or greater than 5 digits.

How can I get the error message "Please enter a valid zip code?" to appear when a user inputs a ZIP code != 5 digits?

Comment: Honestly, I'd tackle this with JS/jQuery instead that way you're giving the user immediate feedback if they're making a mistake rather than waiting for them to submit.  https://gist.github.com/jessegilbride/19d4d18db9f06eb35bbe1d57129aa43e

Comment: Holy crap - this is an example of using the wrong tool for the task. I can't believe I didn't even think about this route.

Thank you

Comment: You're welcome... ...sometimes you get working on something and you get deep into it and everything external to it ends up being beyond grasp.  I had the exact same thing with Canadian Postal Codes and took a break to order something for my kid and the site validated my Postal Code immediately and I was like "Hey!  Why am I not doing this instead?"  Lol!